YOLOv5 works for a very long time on Raspberry Pi 3 B+
To run YOLOv5 on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ I use the Raspberry Pi Camera Module OV5647. Processing a video frame takes 78-82 seconds, which is a lot. In similar projects, it takes no more than 3-4 seconds per frame.
I noticed that YOLOv5 takes the maximum camera resolution and maximum frame rate. This is problem? How to fix it?
niz4@raspberrypi:~/YOLO/yolov5 $ python3 detect.py —weight best_93.pt —source 0
/home/niz4/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py:21: UserWarning: Pandas requires version '2.8.4' or newer of 'numexpr' (version '2.7.2' currently installed).
from pandas.core.computation.check import NUMEXPR_INSTALLED
No Bottleneck unit testing available.
/home/niz4/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/masked.py:60: UserWarning: Pandas requires version '1.3.6' or newer of 'bottleneck' (version '1.2.1' currently installed).
from pandas.core import (
/home/niz4/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/projections/__init__.py:63: UserWarning: Unable to import Axes3D. This may be due to multiple versions of Matplotlib being installed (e.g. as a system package and as a pip package). As a result, the 3D projection is not available.
warnings.warn("Unable to import Axes3D. This may be due to multiple versions of "
detect: weights=['best_93.pt'], source=0, data=data/coco128.yaml, imgsz=[640, 640], conf_thres=0.25, iou_thres=0.45, max_det=1000, device=, view_img=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, nosave=False, classes=None, agnostic_nms=False, augment=False, visualize=False, update=False, project=runs/detect, name=exp, exist_ok=False, line_thickness=3, hide_labels=False, hide_conf=False, half=False, dnn=False, vid_stride=1
requirements: /home/niz4/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requirements.txt not found, check failed.
YOLOv5  v7.0-304-g22361691 Python-3.9.2 torch-1.8.1 CPU

Fusing layers...
YOLOv5s summary: 224 layers, 7167184 parameters, 0 gradients
[ WARN:0@47.168] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1777 open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
1/1: 0... Success (inf frames 2592x1944 at 90.00 FPS)

0: 480x640 (no detections), 78147.3ms
0: 480x640 (no detections), 78018.9ms
0: 480x640 (no detections), 80985.0ms
0: 480x640 (no detections), 80280.2ms

This is all that is written in the terminal.
I tried looking for an option to change the camera resolution. And I found them, but I don't know how to apply them to YOLOv5 :(
Now I'm trying to connect another camera - a webcam to look at the changes. But for the project I need Raspberry Pi Camera Module OV5647.
